# Contacts in List Manager gets replaced by new ones in Sitecore 10.1.0

Tags: xconnect, list-manager, marketing-automation

I followed the below documentation and added a custom submit action in Sitecore 10.1.0.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html

I am running a Marketing Automation that adds contacts to List Manager. But when I add a new Contact, the existing contact gets replaced in the List Manager. As a result, the Contact Count is always 1 in the List Manager.

Any Advice?

Thank You

Comment: Do you always test in same browser? Do you clear cookies or start new incognito mode session? If you always test in the same browser, you just update details of that single contact that is attached to your browser session and never create new one

Comment: I tested in private/incognito mode as well.